# Trying to pass id to the ajax callback function, keeps overwriting, how to solve this?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I created a form which have a lot of images and a delete button on every each one of them. I used ajax to create a callback function which would delete the image. Here is part of my form:

```
foreach($result as $key=>$some){
    $form['image-entry'][$some->id] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset'
    );

    $form['image-entry'][$some->id]['image_' . $some->id] = array(
      '#markup' => theme('image', $variables[$key]),
    );

    $form['image-entry'][$some->id]['description_' . $some->id] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#default_value' => $some->description,
      '#attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => t('Describe this picture'),
       ),
    );
    $form['image-entry'][$some->id]['submit3' . $some->id] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Delete',
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'image_gallery_delete_photo_callback',
       ),
    );
   $form['#foo'] = array($some->id);
  }
```

As you can see I have 3rd submit button which is ajax callback and from example I found out that I need to create a new form element (foo) in this case, which stores some data that I can pass. Everything works like a charm, this is my callback function:

```
function image_gallery_delete_photo_callback($form, $form_state, $args){
  $arguments = $form['#foo'];
  dpm($arguments);

  /*$photo_delete = db_delete('image_gallery_photos')
                  ->condition('id', $arguments)
                  ->execute();*/
}
```

I am able to fetch the id of the photo from the form, but here I face a brick wall.

**Problem:** id is overwritten because it is in a foreach loop, taking it out, doesn't help. It only stores last value from the loop.

How can I get an id of the element selected?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can pass some arguments to your callback by doing this:

```
$form['image-entry'][$some->id]['submit3' . $some->id] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Delete',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'image_gallery_delete_photo_callback',
    'parameters'=> array('param1'=>$some->id)
   ),
);
```

Try to catch those parameters at your function `image_gallery_delete_photo_callback($form, $form_state, $args)`

The variable **$args** should contain 'param1'as your ID

Hope it helps !

Comment: @DarkeK thank you for your answer, but sadly if I try to `dpm($arguments)` I get nothing back. This is how my callback function looks like:

`function image_gallery_delete_photo_callback($form, $form_state, $args){
  $arguments = $args;
  dpm($arguments);

  /*$photo_delete = db_delete('image_gallery_photos')
                  ->condition('id', $arguments)
                  ->execute();*/
}`

Comment: 2 Things, after you changed the form with my answer, did you clean cache? and second, try to capture the first variable, that means "$args" and also do "var_dump($args); exit();", instead the dmp();

Comment: I did what you said and after triggering my ajax callback function I get:

`An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /ImgGallery/drupal-7.50/system/ajax
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: NULL`

Comment: Remove the Exit();